# Google map clickable infowindows from markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api, infowindow

I have this script for links from google map markers:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var locations = [['Test 1','55','13','url1'],['Test 2','45','17','url2']];

  function initialize()
    {
    var myOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(50,15),
        zoom: 3,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE};

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),myOptions);

    setMarkers(map,locations)
    }

  function setMarkers(map,locations)
    {
    var marker, i

    for(i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
      {
      var arr = i
      var name = locations[i][0]
      var lat = locations[i][1]
      var long = locations[i][2]
      var adress = locations[i][3]

      latlngset = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            title: name,
            url: adress,
            position: latlngset  
          });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {window.location.href = this.url;});
      }
    }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  </script>
```

...and, I need generate infowindows from markers instead of links, do you have any simple idea?

Google map clickable infowindows from markers

Comment: What problem are you having adding infoWindows?  - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows

Comment: One infowindow with one marker is ok, but more windows with more markers no :-(

Comment: Perhaps if you posted the code where you tried to do that and ran into problems, someone can find the problem.  Or alternatively, you could search SO, there are lots of similar questions about problems in making that work.